# Login Functionality in MVC c# application with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Will anyone tell how we can apply the login Functionality in mvc application with NHibernate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure google can solve this. If not please post your attempts and we may be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Please build a controller and a related view for this functionality. In the controller you can have a method to check authentication, create new user and set proper roles. The view can be simple using TextBoxFor() razor control on client side and Viewdata dictionary for client server data transfer. The model can be a class based entity using nhibernate. This a very general implementation of mvc which can be used for any web application.